# update though OLE DB transformation in ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

How I can update the table with using inline strean data from package?

ole db source---> Conditional Filter--->     Products --> ind(database table)

```
                                       A             1 to 0

                                       B             1 to 0

                                       C             1 to 0
```

here filter condition filters the input records into three different product(A,B,C) and according to the p_id, I have to update ind in the control table?

Can I do this without touching table ? How to use OLE DB Command over here?

Comment: show select query which you using in Ole db source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your question confusing, but I'll have a go:

Add an OLE DB Command transformation to your Data Flow.  Write a parameterised SQL statement e.g.

update control set ind = ? where p_id = ?

Map your Data Flow columns to the parameters.

Comment: Thanks For Replying Mike,but I am getting ind as 1 in package flow and I have to update it as 0 for those P_ID in different table ...